# How to get a macro to pull the last relevant data from one tab to another?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007, excel-2003

I have a few macros that are working with each other to sort and collate data into relevant tabs, and seem to be having an issue where once the data reaches about row 2500, the macros no longer work correctly.

The first that runs is a sorting (Sort) macro that takes all data and sorts it into relevant columns in a tab I have called 'macrolist' based on their category:

```
Dim LastRow As Integer ', LastCell as String
'
' This is the visual basic to sort the data sheet for excel 2003
    Range("B2:S5002").Select

    Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("D3"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("B3") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("E3"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2:=xlSortNormal, DataOption3:= _
        xlSortNormal 


    'Go to the macrolist sheet and run each filter macro
    Sheets("macrolist").Select
    Application.Run "kittensfilter"
    Application.Run "catsfilter"
    Application.Run "housecatsfilter"
    Application.Run "lionsfilter"
    Application.Run "mountainlionsfilter"
    Application.Run "wbfilter"
    Application.Run "triconfilter"
    Application.Run "schedulefilter"

    'go back to the data sheet and select the last entered job
    Sheets("data").Select

    LastRow = Worksheets("data").Range("U2").Value
    Cells(LastRow, 2).Select

    'selection of a range
    'lastCell = Range(Cells(LastRow, 1), Cells(LastRow, 2)).Address
    'Range(lastCell).Select

    'enter a timestamp
    Worksheets("data").Range("C1") = Time
    Worksheets("data").Range("D1") = Date
```

The two that I'm having problems with are the kittens and puppies filters; it seems when it gets to a certain point on the data tab (about row 2500), they are just stopping from going forward with new information that matches the criteria.  I know this should happen at row 5002, per my code, but it seems to be happening randomly at points before.

Below are the two filters:

```
Sub kittensfilter()

Dim MaxResults As Integer, MyCol As Integer, ResultsRng As String
Dim MyRow As Integer, LastDataRow As Integer, DataRng As String
Dim CritRow As Integer, CritRng As String, RightCol As Integer
Dim TopRow As Integer, BottomRow As Integer, LeftCol As Integer


' the source data MUST be in a worksheet called 'Data'

' *** MODIFY AND SET YOUR OWN RANGES ON THE FOLLOWING DECLARATIONS ***

' cell Data!"?" contains the last row number of data
LastDataRow = Worksheets("data").Range("U2").Value

DataRng = "data!A2:S2" ' range of column headers for Data table
CritRng = "macrolist!C3:U11" ' range of cells for Criteria table
ResultsRng = "macrolist!C13:U13" ' range of headers for Results table
MaxResults = 214 ' any value higher than the number of possible results

' **************** END OF DECLARATIONS *********************

' fix the data range to incorporate the last row

TopRow = Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).Row
LeftCol = Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).Column
RightCol = LeftCol + Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).Columns.Count - 1
DataRng = "data!" & Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftCol), Cells(LastDataRow, RightCol)).Address


' fix the results range to incorporate the last row

TopRow = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(ResultsRng).Row
LeftCol = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(ResultsRng).Column
RightCol = LeftCol + Worksheets("macrolist").Range(ResultsRng).Columns.Count - 1
ResultsRng = "macrolist!" & Range(Cells(TopRow + 1, LeftCol), Cells(MaxResults, RightCol)).Address
Range(ResultsRng).ClearContents ' clear any previous results but not headers
ResultsRng = "macrolist!" & Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftCol), Cells(MaxResults, RightCol)).Address

' fix the criteria range and identify the last row containing any items

TopRow = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Row
BottomRow = TopRow + Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Rows.Count - 1
LeftCol = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Column
RightCol = LeftCol + Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Columns.Count - 1
CritRow = 0

For MyRow = TopRow + 1 To BottomRow
For MyCol = LeftCol To RightCol
If Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value <> "" Then CritRow = MyRow
Next
Next

If CritRow = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Criteria detected", "MeadInKent"
Else
CritRng = "macrolist!" & Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftCol), Cells(CritRow, RightCol)).Address
'Debug.Print "DataRng, CritRng, ResultsRng: ", DataRng, CritRng, ResultsRng

Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Range(CritRng), CopyToRange:=Range(ResultsRng), _
Unique:=False
End If

'Range("A5").Select
Worksheets("black").Range("f4") = Time
Worksheets("black").Range("f5") = Date

End Sub


Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

End Sub










Sub catsfilter()

Dim MaxResults As Integer, MyCol As Integer, ResultsRng As String
Dim MyRow As Integer, LastDataRow As Integer, DataRng As String
Dim CritRow As Integer, CritRng As String, RightCol As Integer
Dim TopRow As Integer, BottomRow As Integer, LeftCol As Integer


' the source data MUST be in a worksheet called 'Data'

' *** MODIFY AND SET YOUR OWN RANGES ON THE FOLLOWING DECLARATIONS ***

' cell Data!"?" contains the last row number of data
LastDataRow = Worksheets("data").Range("U2").Value

DataRng = "data!A2:S2" ' range of column headers for Data table
CritRng = "macrolist!BN3:CF11" ' range of cells for Criteria table
ResultsRng = "macrolist!BN13:CF13" ' range of headers for Results table
MaxResults = 214 ' any value higher than the number of possible results

' **************** END OF DECLARATIONS *********************

' fix the data range to incorporate the last row

TopRow = Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).Row
LeftCol = Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).Column
RightCol = LeftCol + Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).Columns.Count - 1
DataRng = "data!" & Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftCol), Cells(LastDataRow, RightCol)).Address


' fix the results range to incorporate the last row

TopRow = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(ResultsRng).Row
LeftCol = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(ResultsRng).Column
RightCol = LeftCol + Worksheets("macrolist").Range(ResultsRng).Columns.Count - 1
ResultsRng = "macrolist!" & Range(Cells(TopRow + 1, LeftCol), Cells(MaxResults, RightCol)).Address
Range(ResultsRng).ClearContents ' clear any previous results but not headers
ResultsRng = "macrolist!" & Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftCol), Cells(MaxResults, RightCol)).Address

' fix the criteria range and identify the last row containing any items

TopRow = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Row
BottomRow = TopRow + Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Rows.Count - 1
LeftCol = Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Column
RightCol = LeftCol + Worksheets("macrolist").Range(CritRng).Columns.Count - 1
CritRow = 0

For MyRow = TopRow + 1 To BottomRow
For MyCol = LeftCol To RightCol
If Cells(MyRow, MyCol).Value <> "" Then CritRow = MyRow
Next
Next

If CritRow = 0 Then
MsgBox "No Criteria detected", "MeadInKent"
Else
CritRng = "macrolist!" & Range(Cells(TopRow, LeftCol), Cells(CritRow, RightCol)).Address
'Debug.Print "DataRng, CritRng, ResultsRng: ", DataRng, CritRng, ResultsRng

Worksheets("data").Range(DataRng).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
CriteriaRange:=Range(CritRng), CopyToRange:=Range(ResultsRng), _
Unique:=False
End If

'Range("A5").Select
Worksheets("finished").Range("C4") = Time
Worksheets("finished").Range("C5") = Date

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub
```

These both take the information presented in the 'macrolist' tab and copy it over into the respective 'kittens' and 'cats' tabs.

I think that the main problem is with the sorting function, but I can't figure out what I should change to make it continue to perform as needed.  I have already tried increasing/decreasing the ranges, but they seem to make no effect.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with the debugger?  What is it doing at the row where things get wonky?  Is it filtering how you expect?  On a side note, consider storing your range variables as `Range` instead of `String` then all the `Range(ResultsRng)` peices will just become `ResultsRng`.

Comment: Running the debugger on it produces no results; the debugger believes it works fine--this is why I can't quite figure out what is going on. 

On the row that it begins to get wonky, it stops sorting/filtering the data into the 'macrolist' worksheet and subsequently into the 'kittens' and 'cats' worksheets.

And thank you for the tip; I will go ahead and change that.